# C# Windows Form datagridviewcomboboxcell is not valid while clearing the datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer

I am having a Datagridview with a datagridviewcombobox.

Based on the windows form search criteria grid will be populated.

After search grid is populated with results and also combobox with some values.

After doing some operations grid should be cleared off.

Status.Items.Clear();
 grd.Rows.Clear();

I am getting this error.

DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid at line grd.Rows.Clear();

Also i am not assighing datasoure to grid directly.

We are mapping each column Like

grid.Rows[index].Cells["XYZ"].Value

Also Combo box will be populated on click of that column

cmbdrpdown.Items.Add('test');

Comment: I bet you are using a datasource to fill your datagridview

Comment: Is the combobox databound or also not?

Comment: Plese add more code regarding setup and use of the DataGridView.

Comment: @Jyo You say the combobox will be populated, is the combobox itself added programmatically?